# ExecutorService: FIFO ordering by key

Tags: java, concurrency, java-threads

I'm looking for ways to make an ExecutorService be FIFO ordered by an object (key), i.e.

1. For a given key, events will be processed in the order they arrived.
2. For a given key, only one event will be processed at a time.

Netty 3 has [OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/execution/OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor.html) but it is tied to Netty.

Guava has [EventBus](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained) but it's unclear whether or not it guarantees FIFO.

I could lock on the key using something like [JKeyLockManager](https://github.com/mojgh/JKeyLockManager) but to guarantee FIFO I would have to risk contention in the dispatcher thread.

Are there any general solutions to this problem out there?

Comment: Use Akka actors (a bit more complex than an `ExecutorService`, but your requirements are built-in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want simplicity, I would use a number of FIFO executors like this

```
static final int executors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2;
ExecutorService[] executors = new ExecutorService[executors];
// fill with single threaded executors.

public Future submit(Object actorId, Runnable r) {
    int h = (actorId.hashCode() & 0x7FFF_FFFF) % executors;
    return executors[h].submit(r);
}
```

Unless the workload is highly unbalanced this will keep all your CPUs busy, without the need for locking.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there any reason to use & 0x7FFF_FFFF over Math.abs()?

Comment: @bcoughlan yes, Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) == Integer.MIN_VALUE, which would be a surprise 1 in 4 billion times. i.e. hard to discover via testing.